# Two tables in one management

Tags: database-design, grocery-crud

[image]

Above is my database design.

Here in my database design I have a otherinfo table. This table contains details related to a student if a student belong to a certain department. This is because not all department joins with sport events.

Is it possible to manage this two tables into one?

Example:

table:

[image]

in add/edit:

[image]

And then after saving... the details will be inserted in the two tables or in just one table if, like I said, the department chosen is not active with sports.

Is there a way to do this the easy way with the current functionalities available..? but I'm also open with a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your explanation what I think is:

Other Information should be in student table because when department is sports then other information is comes in, so we can save it in same table.

I don't think making a new table for other information.

Departments in new table is ok as there can be multiple tables however if there are other information for 1 department then we can save it in Student table itself.